# Using Apache POI to update text in a textbox in excel but retain formatting

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using Excel sheets as a method of creating certificates and simple reports using Apache POI, the data is to be placed in formatted textboxes in the excel sheet. 
I was hoping to get the TextBox object from the sheet and just change the text but while I can get the RichTextString I cannot find a way to replace the text.
My next plan is to get each individual font characteristic, create a new RichTextString with the new text and then set the font characteristics. This is fiddly but not too difficult but I have a tendency to go for the complex solution when a simple one exists.

Is there a simple method to just change the text in a textbox and keep the formatting and font characteristcs?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you.

```
HSSFFont font = workBook.createFont();
font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 10);
font.setFontName("Arial");
font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);


HSSFCellStyle style = workBook.createCellStyle();
style.setFont(font);


HSSFCell myCell = row.createCell(spalte);
myCell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Text");
myCell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not really what I am after. this is building a font and then applying it which I am familiar with but I need to extract an existing Font object from a RichTestString and apply it to another one (or just change the text). RichTextString has an apply(Font) method but the getFont methods return short and not the whole Font object.

Comment: Not applicable in this case, the strings are not in a cell they are in Excel Textboxes (HSSFShapes) and not in Cells.